# My Firebase is not retrieving data from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have seen many other similar questions and also tried their method but still its not working.

[image: My Database Pic]

My getFirebase function on a Click Listener :

```
 private void getFirebase() {
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Questions/m1");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Log.d("QuizFragment", "getfirebase");

    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("QuizFragment", " Snapshots");
            list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("QuizFragment", "error  " + databaseError.toString());
        }
    });
    Log.d("QuizFragment","debug");
}
```

My Logcat is showing getFirebase and then directly debug message.
I have seen many answer to wait for execution of SingleEvent but I have waited for many time still its not showing. Note : I am running app on emulator

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you edit your question to show the logcat output from your `Log.d` calls?

Comment: Does `Log.d("QuizFragment", "error  " + databaseError.toString());` print something? Is `onDataChange` or `onCancelled` even triggered? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo no it didn't print anything. They are not triggered i guess because it did not print anything on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addListenerForSingleValueEvent will get the data from the local disk cache.If you don't have any data in your cache you won't get any data.i believe that's why you could not get into onDataChange(). so first get data at least once like this

```
 firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Questions/m1")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
            }
            else {
                Log.d("firebase", String.valueOf(task.getResult().getValue()));
            }
        }
    });

//then use cache data.  

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("QuizFragment", " Snapshots");
            list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("QuizFragment", "error  " + databaseError.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: That Complete Listener worked for me I guess btw thanks for the help and may I know why I got a minus 1 mark on my question please ?