# Database reference valueEventListener not called

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, one-time-password

I have an application where i register the user using phone number authentication , everything works fine but as the user is done verifying the phone number , i would like to push some credentials of the user to
realtime datbase , but the issue is that i'm not able to do so ... stuck basically , if any one could i'll appreciate it

- This is my code

```
  private fun signInWithAuthPhoneCredentials(credentials: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credentials)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if(it.isSuccessful){
                    
              // so basically if authentication is successful , i want to create a path to save user
              // credentials which dosn't exist in the first place , upon checking if snapshot dosn't
              // exist , i want to get user details and push them into database
              // even with debugging , it gets to the last line of ( valueEventlister) and it stops 
              // there , it dson't even get to check wether snapshot exists or not 
 
                    val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
                    if(currentUser != null){
                        val databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users").child(currentUser.uid)
                        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
                            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                if(!snapshot.exists()){
                                    val contactInfoMap = hashMapOf<String,Any>()
                                    contactInfoMap["name"] = currentUser.displayName!!
                                    contactInfoMap["phone"] = currentUser.phoneNumber!!

                                    databaseReference.updateChildren(contactInfoMap)
                                }

                                userIsLoggedIn()
                            }

                            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                            }
                        })
                    }

                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d("ERROR TAG","Error ${it.message}")
            }
    }
```

Comment: [please check here ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648514/my-firebase-is-not-retrieving-data-from-firebase-database/67654578#67654578)

Comment: ”It gets to the last line of (ValueEventListener)”. What do you mean by that? Since the snapshot.exists-check doesn’t execute I’d look into my val databaseReference. Is it correct? Lastly, are you sure the user you’re testing with doesn’t actually exist? That could explain why !snapshot.exists() is false.

Comment: @androidLearner what i want to say is that the database when the user is authenicating via his phone number , at start there is no data for sure ( could be the issue why ) but i'm following sim coder on youtube , he did it and it worked but i'm not sure why it is not working with me , so basically at first when the user creates a new account , database is empty , so it is empty i create a map and pass the data of the user to save

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo i'm not getting any error but onDataChanged() is not called and i guess the reason because path doesnt exist yet , i'm checking for a path that dosn't exist , that's why i'm checking if !snapshots.exists , i want to push some data , i'm followin a course of sim coder , i can share the link the video if you want , thank you

Comment: Is any for onDataChange or onCancelled even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo no not at all , they are not trigged , i don't know how the other guy did , it basically check for a path that dosnt exit ..i'm not sure what is wrong

Comment: Again, are you sure you’re listening for events on a node (child) that has data? Is your databaseReference pointing to the correct node in your database?

Comment: I’d also check if your currentUser is indeed null. Catch that with an else-block and see if you end up there

Comment: @DanAbnormal the currentUser is actually not null after the user is done confirming phone , basically the block after currentUser != null dosnt work

Comment: Can you perhaps add your database structure?

Comment: Now that I look at your code, I can’t see the point of the databaseListener. For one, you are not using the snapshot. And you say you know currentUser is not null. As far as I can tell you could just set the values to your database, without listening for value events

Comment: @DanAbnormal thank you for your answer , yeah i have debugge my app and user is not null , the issue is with saving data in db ( not the user itself ) , this is the video i'm following please take at it if you want to from ( 6:50 until 10:30 of the video ) 
 https://youtu.be/BcWta8wO1kg?list=PLxabZQCAe5fgGQggJxp5nuI1ESzP-oMED

Comment: This video doesn’t show where you go wrong. Please try and follow my advice. See my comments above

Comment: @DanAbnormal i'm following a whole course and what is saved inside on DataChanged is crucial , those saved data will at some be the point to the next step , what better way could you suggest please ? thank you

Comment: I don’t know what the course will do later on, but for now I see no reason for the valueEventListener. Please see my earlier comments

Comment: @DanAbnormal i found a way to handle the situation , may not be the best solution but it does the job, i have sharepreferences if first time launched i will directly save the user details , if not first time i will check the user , then i ll use the listener to check for the user details , what do you think about this approach ?

Comment: I think sharepref is local. If a user gets a new device (or maybe even reinstalls the app on same device) the data will be lost. A server backend like firebase is the way to go when saving user data.

Comment: You should try to make the first approach work, where you grab data from firebase

Comment: Somehow you should try and understand if a user exists or not, and handle the saving of userDetails according to that. I’d say checking if uid exists is a good approach. But somehow - I can’t see why exactly - your logic doesn’t work.

Comment: Can you try, in your onCompleteListener, to grab the user by doing val user = it.result?.user, and then grab uid from that user and do your database check?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, upgrading google-services.json worked for me. You can find it in the firebase project settings -> SDK setup and configuration.